# How to cite an article from a webmagazine, which is between an article and a webpage

Tags: bibtex, citing

I found an article in the web magazine from Sony "CX-news"  [as PDF](http://www.sony.net/Products/SC-HP/cx_news/vol62/pdf/sideview62.pdf) and [as website](http://www.sony.net/Products/SC-HP/cx_news/vol62/sideview1.html). It is not exactly an article (it has no clear author, but the name of the magazine and the volume number) and its not just a unspecific webpage. How should in such an "in-between case" the citation look like and what information to put where in the bibtex file? The PDF contains more information and is thus probably better to cite.

Answer (score 2):

How the citation should look depends on the style you are using.

In your case I would use

- title: "OTFT-Driven OLED Display that can be Rolled up onto a Pen",
- publisher: magazin name,
- year,
- volume and
- url of webpage or url of pdf.

The kind of entry depends on your style (what does it offer?). Possible could be

- article,
- misc or
- online.

I would prefer to cite the pdf file because I can download it for later consultation/reading. A webpage can vanish. And if the pdf contains all the important information in an compact form, I would prefer it.

Comment: My current stile is statto.bst, which might change. The bibliography includes for articles authors, journal, title and the title hyperlinked to the location of the paper. However for this citation the link should explicitly appear. And to the best of my knowledge none of the entry types includes all possibilites (e.g. title, pbulisher, year, volume)